# Unity 3D Animation fbx

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Please see this image

[image]

I make a script called reload :

```
#pragma strict

function Update () {
 if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.R)){
    animation.Play("Take 001");
  }
}
```

But when I press R :

> MissingComponentException:
>
> There is not "Animation"  attached to the "AK" game object, but a script is trying to access it.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an Animation component. If you click the "Add Component" button, and search for Animation, you'll see the component you need to add.

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between "Animator" and "Animation" component.

In order to use animation.play() you need to have an Animation component where the clip would be added(here the clip name should be "Take 001"). This is he legacy animation system. You need to import your fbx as legacy.

Here in your screenshot, its the Animator component that is used which takes the controller. Its the mecanim animation system.